# IF and ELSE statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to award a user a badge if their points are 10,000. There is a field in the table called badge1 with a default value set to **locked** and a points row. I am running and **if statement** that if the users points are 10,000 then UPDATE the badge1 row from locked to unlocked. My code seems correct but It is neither updating the the field nor showing any errors.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$q = "SELECT Points FROM login_users WHERE username ='$username'");
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$Points = $row['Points'];


if($Points == "10000") {
   $awardBadge = $db->exec("UPDATE login_users SET badge1=unlocked WHERE username=?");
$Points->execute(array($username))
} else {
    print "";
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

**I managed to get it working.. however the problem is I am a bit new to converting old sql to PDO so this is not very secure but this is what works:**

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$username = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];
$q = "SELECT Points FROM login_users WHERE username = ('$username')";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$Points = $row['Points'];

?> 

// Place somewhere
<?php
if($Points >= "10000") {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE login_users SET maneki='unlocked' WHERE username='$username'");
} else {
    print "Badge has not been unlocked";

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_*` AND PDO?  What a mess... just use PDO.  Also, your code as-is right now is likely wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Are you sure that their points are exactly 10000?

Comment: "If statement not updating table" --- the title makes no sense.

Comment: Is your if statement being executed at all?

Comment: @peterbond it is not being excuted at all.

Comment: @AoiHana: then `$points` is not equal to `10000`

Comment: Very strange because the field is 10000 :(

Comment: @AoiHana: `var_dump($Points == "10000", $points);` and show us the result

Comment: @zerkms the result was bool(false) NULL

Comment: @AoiHana: so you see - `$points` equals to `NULL`, not to `10000` as you thought. `var_dump($row);` and check what's in the row array. **ALWAYS** check the **ACTUAL** value of the variable, never trust to anything but facts.

Comment: @zerkms thank you for that advice. I will definitely do that from now on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19019/discussion-between-aoihana-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"10000" string` should be an `10000 int`

And also, you might want to make a choice here too. You're using 2 types of setting up a mysql-database connection. the old-fashioned `mysql_function()` way and the new fancy `PDO method`.

I think working with the PDO version is safer, since newer PHP versions will not support the old methods anymore... That... and it just looks dirty ;P

Try this:

```
<?php

session_start();

$dbSession = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***');

$selectQuery = $dbSession->prepare('
  SELECT `User`.`Points`
  FROM `login_users` AS `User`
  WHERE `User`.`username` = :username
');
$selectQuery->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$user = $selectQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ( !empty($user) && $user['Points'] == 10000 ) {
  $updateQuery = $dbSession->prepare('
    UPDATE `login_users`
    SET `badge1` = \'unlocked\'
    WHERE `username` = :username');
  $updateQuery->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $updateQuery->execute();
}

?>
```

Usefull resources:

- [PHP Database Objects (PDO)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
- [MySQL Datamanipulation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html)
- [MySQL SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)
- [MySQL UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this! For some reason it keeps logging the user out on the page I have this placed on.. really strange.  I updated my above description with the old sql code that functions properly but sadly it is mysql and not PDO. Again, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @AoiHana I've added `session_start();`, that's probably it

Comment: @AoiHana and I've added some useful links to some documentation, which explains more about the inner workings.

Comment: That was it :) And thank you so much for those resources! I really appreciate your help on all of this conversation to PDO.

Comment: ""10000" string should be an 10000 int" --- who told so?

Answer (score 1):

Better check if >= 10000 and not yet awarded. That could you also be done in SQL so you don't need that logic in PHP.

```
UPDATE login_users SET badge1=unlocked WHERE points >= 10000 and badget1 <> unlocked
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `if($Points == 10000)` instead of `if($Points == "10000")`

`mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Comment: Both are equal (in this case). Not an answer

Comment: That is nonsense to reoen the connection for two querries

Comment: `"10000" string` should be an 10000 `int`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by `$point` value which actually is not equal to `10000`, but is `NULL`.

So I propose to always use `var_dump()` to get the actual value of the variable in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

one tip: check the PDO docs, before you write php code! You use PDO and mysql commands on same time for same job!?? why???

Answer (score 0):

```
if($Points==10000){
    $awardBadge = $db->prepare("UPDATE login_users SET badge1=unlocked WHERE username=?");
    $awardBadge->execute(array($username));
}
```